# How to make a "Solver" in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm working on Jupyter Notebook with pandas.
Here are some lines:

```
df['muy_s'] = 10**(np.log10(df['Density'])+(1/df['Denominator'])-2.17)
df['Vpc'] = df['Regressed Vc']*df ['zi']
df['rho_r'] = (df['Density']*62.427)*df['Vpc']/df ['Mwi']
df['muy_i'] = (34*(10**-5))*(1/df['zeta'])*(df['Tri']**0.94)
df['zeta_T'] = 5.4402*(df['Tpc']**(1/6))/((df ['Mwi']**0.5)*(df['ppc']**(2/3)))
df['RHS'] =A0+(A1*df['rho_r'])+(A2*(df['rho_r']**2))+(A3*(df['rho_r']**3))+(A4*(df['rho_r']**4))
df['muy_0'] = df ['zi']*df['muy_i']*(df ['Mwi']**0.5)/(df ['zi']*(df ['Mwi']**0.5))
df['muy_lbc'] = df['muy_0']+((1/df['zeta_T'])*(df['RHS']**4))-0.0001
error =(df['muy_s']-df['muy_lbc'])**2
```

I have values for: `df['muy_s']`, `df['muy_lbc']`, `df['Regressed Vc']`.

I want values from `df['muy_s']` = `df['muy_lbc']` by changing values of `df['Regressed Vc']` which means: error = 0 or minimum.

Just like what "Solver" does in Excel.

My df is a table which has 40 rows and I don't know how to do the loop for it.

Hope anyone could understand and help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Would you express your problem mathematically, with a sample before/after `df`?  It's difficult to understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a Newton-Raphson solver. It can only find one zero of your function, so be warned that any solution might not be unique. Change the `startX` value if you want to find other solutions.

```
def linSolve(func, delta=1e-4, epsilon=1e-4, startX=0, recursionLimit=2000):
    x = startX
    nudgeNext = False
    epsilonSquared = epsilon**2
    for r in range(recursionLimit-1):
        y = func(x)
        if y**2 < epsilonSquared:
            return x
        elif nudgeNext:
            x += delta
            y = func(x)
            nudgeNext = False
        gradient = (func(x + delta) - y)/delta
        if gradient != 0:
            x -= y/gradient
        else:
            nudgeNext = True
    y = func(x)
    if y**2 < epsilonSquared:
        return x
    return float("nan")

myQuadratic = lambda x: x**2 - x - 1
print(f"x\N{SUPERSCRIPT TWO} - x - 1: x = {linSolve(myQuadratic)}")
myCubic = lambda x: x**3 - 2*x**2 + 3*x - 4
print(f"x\N{SUPERSCRIPT THREE} - 2x\N{SUPERSCRIPT TWO} + 3x - 4: {linSolve(myCubic)}")
```

You're welcome to copy the above code if you'd like. All you need to do is simplify the equation for the difference between `df['muy_s']` and `df['muy_lbc']` and put them in a list, let's call it `myFuncs`, choose delta and epsilon values, do something like `[linSolve(myFunc) for myFunc in myFuncs]` and you've got your list.